# Does using list_for_each_entry() in rcu reader side critical section cause problems?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, rcu

In the Linux kernel, `list_for_each_entry_rcu()` is used to traverse rcu protected list in reader side critical section. What happens if `list_for_each_entry()` is used instead? Does it cause problems?

Comment: Yes... yes it does. That is exactly why `list_for_each_entry_rcu` exists :')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some architectures CPUs can look through the next pointer early. Specially in case of ALPHA and SPARC CPUs. Hence `list_for_each_entry_rcu()` is needed which essentially put memory barriers to limit this behavior. However in writer side we can avoid `list_for_each_entry_rcu()` and use `list_for_each_entry()`.

Comment: Does it cause problems in architectures like x86 or arm when using list_for_each_entry() in rcu reader side?

Comment: Is there any guarantee that x86 / arm will behave same in future too? 

Presently, list_for_each_entry_rcu() differ from its ancestor on two grounds.

1. It includes call to __list_check_rcu() —> which will complain loudly if you are calling this API out of rcu_read_(un)lock(), provided lockdep is configured.
2. Has compiler only memory barrier READ_ONCE() except DEC Alpha.  

READ_ONCE behaviour can change in case of ARM when building with LTO.